# Python calculation of LennardJones 2D interaction pair correlation distribution function in Grand Canonical Ensemble

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, histogram, physics, montecarlo

*Edit*
I believe there is a problem with the normalization of the histogram, since one must divide with the radius of each element.

---

I am trying trying to calculate the fluctuations of particle number and the radial distribution function of a 2d LennardJones(LJ) system using python3. Although I believe the particle fluctuations come out right, the pair correlation g(r) come right for small distances but then blow up ( the calculation uses numpy's histogram method).

The thing is, I can' t find out why such a behavior emerges- perhaps of some misunderstanding of a method? As it is, I am posting the relevant code right below, and if needed, I could also upload other parts of the code or the entire script.

Note first, that since we are working with the Grand-Canonical Ensemble, as the number of particles changes, *so is the array that stores the particles- and perhaps that's another point where a mistake in implementation could exist.*

**Particle removal or insertion**

```
def mcex(L,npart,particles,beta,rho0,V,en):
    factorin=(rho0*V)/(npart+1)
    factorout=(npart)/(V*rho0)
    print("factorin=",factorin)
    print("factorout",factorout)
    # Produce random number and check:
    rand = random.uniform(0, 1)
    if rand <= 0.5:
        # Insert a particle at a random location
        x_new_coord = random.uniform(0, L)
        y_new_coord = random.uniform(0, L)  
        new_particle = [x_new_coord,y_new_coord]
        new_E = particleEnergy(new_particle,particles, npart+1)         
        deltaE = new_E          
        print("dEin=",deltaE)
        # Acceptance rule for inserting
        if(deltaE>10):
            P_in=0
        else:
            P_in = (factorin) *math.exp(-beta*deltaE)
        print("pinacc=",P_in)                   
        rand= random.uniform(0, 1)
        if rand <= P_in :                           
            particles.append(new_particle)
            en += deltaE                            
            npart += 1
            print("accepted insertion")
    else:
        if npart != 0:                              
            p = random.randint(0, npart-1)              
            this_particle = particles[p]
            prev_E = particleEnergy(this_particle, particles, p)
            deltaE = prev_E
            print("dEout=",deltaE)
            # Acceptance rule for removing
            if(deltaE>10):
                P_re=1
            else:
                P_re = (factorout)*math.exp(beta*deltaE)
            print("poutacc=",P_re)
            rand = random.uniform(0, 1)
            if rand <= P_re :   
                particles.remove(this_particle)
                en += deltaE 
                npart = npart - 1
                print("accepted removal")
    print()
    return particles, en, npart
```

**Monte Carlo relevant part: for 1/10 runs, check the possibility of inserting or removing a particle**

```
# MC
for step in range(0, runTimes):
    print(step)
    print()
    rand = random.uniform(0,1)
    if rand <= 0.9:
        #----------- change energies-------------------------
        #........
        #........

    else:
        particles, en, N = mcex(L,N,particles,beta,rho0,V, en)
        # stepList.append(step)

    if((step+1)%1000==0):
        for i, particle1 in enumerate(particles):
            for j, particle2 in enumerate(particles):
                if j!= i:
                    # print(particle1)
                    # print(particle2)
                    # print(i)
                    # print(j)
                    dist.append(distancesq(particle1, particle2))

    NList.append(N)
```

**where we call the function mcex *and perhaps the particles array is not updated correctly*:**

```
def mcex(L,npart,particles,beta,rho0,V,en):
    factorin=(rho0*V)/(npart+1)
    factorout=(npart)/(V*rho0)
    print("factorin=",factorin)
    print("factorout",factorout)
    # Produce random number and check:
    rand = random.uniform(0, 1)
    if rand <= 0.5:
        # Insert a particle at a random location
        x_new_coord = random.uniform(0, L)
        y_new_coord = random.uniform(0, L)  
        new_particle = [x_new_coord,y_new_coord]
        new_E = particleEnergy(new_particle,particles, npart+1)         
        deltaE = new_E          
        print("dEin=",deltaE)
        # Acceptance rule for inserting
        if(deltaE>10):
            P_in=0
        else:
            P_in = (factorin) *math.exp(-beta*deltaE)
        print("pinacc=",P_in)                   
        rand= random.uniform(0, 1)
        if rand <= P_in :                           
            particles.append(new_particle)
            en += deltaE                            
            npart += 1
            print("accepted insertion")
    else:
        if npart != 0:                              
            p = random.randint(0, npart-1)              
            this_particle = particles[p]
            prev_E = particleEnergy(this_particle, particles, p)
            deltaE = prev_E
            print("dEout=",deltaE)
            # Acceptance rule for removing
            if(deltaE>10):
                P_re=1
            else:
                P_re = (factorout)*math.exp(beta*deltaE)
            print("poutacc=",P_re)
            rand = random.uniform(0, 1)
            if rand <= P_re :   
                particles.remove(this_particle)
                en += deltaE 
                npart = npart - 1
                print("accepted removal")
    print()
    return particles, en, npart
```

**and finally, we create the g(r) histogramm**

*where perhaps the normalization or the use of the histogram method are not as they should* 
   `RDF(N,particles,L)`

with the function:

```
def RDF(N,particles, L):
    minb=0
    maxb=8
    nbin=500


    skata=np.asarray(dist).flatten()    
    rDf = np.histogram(skata, np.linspace(minb, maxb,nbin)) 
    prefactor = (1/2/ np.pi)* (L**2/N **2) /len(dist) *( nbin /(maxb -minb) )   
    # prefactor = (1/(2* np.pi))*(L**2/N**2)/(len(dist)*num_increments/(rMax + 1.1 * dr ))                  
    rDf = [prefactor*rDf[0], 0.5*(rDf[1][1:]+rDf[1][:-1])]
    print('skata',len(rDf[0]))
    print('incr',len(rDf[1]))

    plt.figure()    
    plt.plot(rDf[1],rDf[0])
    plt.xlabel("r")
    plt.ylabel("g(r)")

    plt.show()
```

The results are:

[image: Particle N number fluctuations]

Particle N number fluctuations

and

[[image: Pair Correlation[2]]

but we want

[image: correct pair correlation]

Comment: I am starting to think there is a problem with normalization

Comment: Perhaps I need to divide each element of the histogram[0] with the value of the distance or the bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your g(r) is not correctly normalised. You need to divide the number of pairs found in each bin by the average density of the system times the area of the annulus associated to that bin, where the latter is just 2 pi r dr, with r being the bin's midpoint and dr the bin size. As far as I can tell, your prefactor does not contain the "r" bit. There is also something else that is missing, but it's hard to tell without knowing what all the other constants contain.

EDIT: [here](http://www.physics.emory.edu/faculty/weeks/idl/gofr2.html) is a link that will guide you the implementation of a routine to compute the radial distribution function in 2D and 3D

Answer (score 2):

Although I have accepted an answer, I am posting here some more details.

To normalize the pair correlation correctly one must divide each "number of particles found at a certain distance" or mathematically the sum of delta function of the distances , one must divide with the distance it's self.

Understanding first that a numpy.histogram is an array of two elements, first element the array of all counted events and second element the vector of bins, one must take each element of the first array, lets say np.histogram[0] and multiply it pairwise with np.histogram[1] of the second array.

That is, one must do the following:

```
def RDF(N,particles, L):
minb=0
maxb=25
nbin=200
width=(maxb-minb)/(nbin)




rings=np.linspace(minb, maxb,nbin)
skata=np.asarray(dist).flatten()
rDf = np.histogram(skata, rings ,density=True)
prefactor = (1/( np.pi*(L**2/N**2)))
rDf = [prefactor*rDf[0], 0.5*(rDf[1][1:]+rDf[1][:-1])]
rDf[0]=np.multiply(rDf[0],1/(rDf[1]*( width )))
```

where before the last multiply line, we are centering the bins so that their numbers equals the number of elements of the first array( you have five fingers, but four intermediate gaps between them)